# Python KeyError column name not in index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

another newbie question from me. Have following dataframe from Excel and I get the error, can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong, thank you:

EDIT:
here are the columns from the Excel

```
+----+--------+------+----+----+---+----+-----+----+-----+----+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+------------+------+----------+-------+------------+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+-----+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
| Rk | Player | From | To | Tm | G | GS | Yrs | PB | AP1 | AV | GS/Yr | AV/Yr | QB_score | Height | Height-in | Weight | BMI | School | BCS School | 40YD | Vertical | Bench | Broad Jump | 3cone | Shuttle | Cmp | Att | Pct | Yds | AY/A | TD | Int | Rate | Rush_Att  | Rush_Yds | Rush_Avg | Rush_TD |
+----+--------+------+----+----+---+----+-----+----+-----+----+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-----+--------+------------+------+----------+-------+------------+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+----+-----+------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

> KeyError: "['Rush_Att'] not in index"

```
df = pd.read_excel('sportsref-qbdata-raw-v2.xlsx', header=1)

cols_to_keep = ['Player', 'QB_score', 'Height-in', 'Weight', 'BMI', 'BCS School', 'Cmp', 'Att', 'Pct', 'Yds', 'AY/A', 'TD', 'Int', 'Rate', 'Rush_Att', 'Rush_Yds', 'Rush_Avg', 'Rush_TD']

df = df[cols_to_keep]
```

Comment: Can you post the Excel file? It seems like one of the columns does not exist, but I cannot really be sure without looking at the file

Comment: The columns all exist, I added them myself

Comment: I believe you, of course, but in order to debug your problem, I still need the file...

Comment: Are these column names?

Comment: Yes, these are the column names

Comment: @liorr I can't attach a file here, but I added the exact column names from the Excel

Comment: @MJ95, you can upload it to a cloud service like GoogleDrive and provide the link

Comment: It seems to be a space in the `Rush_Att `  column name (Just a guess).

Comment: @Saeed that was it, thanks! I thought I checked like 3 times for any leading or trailing spaces, better to always trim

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `header = 1` because you only have 1 row of header, remove header parameter, or use `header = 0` or `header = [0]`